# No support for multi-line MACROs during WPP tracing

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, logging, trace, etw

I'm adding tracing to a user-mode application based on "Event Tracing for Windows" (ETW) using WPP (a pre-processor) and visual studio compiler.

This [MSDN content](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff597683%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) explains how convert existing macros to allow tracing from within them. The example there is CHECK_HR, which gets a single argument (HR) and generates a trace if it is not 0.

Now, I found that the generated pre-processor function don't work if the argument is multi-line, due to the way WPP works. But I could not find any reference to such a problem!

```
CHECK_HR(DoSomething(a,b,c)); // works   
CHECK_HR(DoSomething(a,  
    b, c)); // don't work
```

Problem is that when the macro is encountered by the pre-processor in line 17 of File.cpp wpp it generates a function called something like wpp_File_cpp17 and uses **LINE** to call it from the macro. But for multi-line macro as above the __ LINE__ will be 18 and one will get an error:

```
wpp_File_cpp18: unknown function
```

Does anyone have a work-around for this issue? I know MSFT use WPP extensively internally, I wonder how they handle this...

Comment: I have confirmed the behavior which don't support multi-line macros also in the DDK sample!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to reproduce this issue, without success -- multi-line WPP calls work for me, so the error you're getting seems kind of weird. Did you modify the `CHECK_HR` macro in any way?

You could try putting slashes at the end of each line of the call:

```
CHECK_HR(DoSomething(a, \
                     b, \
                     c));
```

Also, in your example you're missing a closing parenthesis, this causes WPP_CALL_blahblah_undefined. But most likely that's just a typo in this example.

Comment: Interesting! Which version of the DDK do you use?

Comment: I'm using Windows 8 DDK (Consumer Preview).